# How to change the port number for Docker image of Kibana

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I am running Kibana using Docker

Below is the docker-compose that I am using for running Kibana Fluentd and Elastic-Search.

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    expose:
      - 9200
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - cloud      


  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
    links:
      - "elasticsearch"
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
    networks:
      - cloud  


  kibana:
    image: kibana
    links:
      - "elasticsearch"
    ports:
      - "9201:5601"
    networks:
      - cloud

networks:
  cloud:
   driver: bridge
```

My Problem statement is as below:

I want to run the Kibana on `9201` port. I have mention the same in docker-compose.yml 
still It get run on its default port `5601`

[image]

Please Let me know what changes I need to do for running Kibana on `9201`

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
kibana:
image: kibana
links:
  - "elasticsearch"
ports:
  - "9201:5601"
networks:
  - cloud
```

Edit :

Explanation : 
Your service kabana is running on the port 5601 of the container. So

```
ports:
   -"9201:5601"
```

links the port 5601 of the container to the port 9201 of the host machine.

Comment: I have change the port in docker-compose as per @Vamsi mention.The reason why I want to change the Port is `5601` is blocked for getting called from Outside VM. 

still If I call `http://host-name:9201`  I get Connection Time-Out.

My Problem remain the same. 

Please suggest If I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Make sure that your container is up. From which  machine are you trying to access the service kabana? Is that different from where the docker containers are running?

Comment: All the containers are running on ubuntu machine where I have docker setup. I am trying to access the container from outside VM like any public internet. I am calling the services using api-gateway using zuul routes. I can see the call are landing to api-gateway. eg `http://hostname:9201` it's not forwarding the request to kibana 5601

Comment: Could it be a problem related to kibana image??

Comment: @Binary I am not sure , I am implementing Kibana first time , I am using the docker image `kibana:
    image: kibana`

Comment: I am also facing the same problem in another kind of non-MSA application. I am thinking to enroll the application on Eureka and calling the application using zuul routes.Not sure if we can register the service on Eureka using docker-compose

Comment: Can you try running localhost:9201 on the machine where the docker containers are running?. Also login to the docker container and check if the kibana service is running properly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the port via the `SERVER_PORT` environment variable. It's very practical when you're running the container in the `host` network.

Answer (score 2):

you have no control over the image's internal port but you can map the internal port "5601" to the port you want "9201" as @Vamsi answer above

Comment: I have done the change still My problem remain the same.

Comment: it seems that there is some enviroment variables that needs to be set in docker compose file as per the following documentation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/_configuring_kibana_on_docker.html